# Passing two different signals through common NAND gates twice

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, boolean-algebra

Two signals **X** & **Y** are passed through common NAND gates twice, i.e.,

```
 (X NAND Y) ---> NAND GATE
```

Algebraically, the solution comes as follows:

```
=(X NAND Y) NAND (X NAND Y)
=(X•Y)' NAND (X•Y)'
=[(X•Y)' • (X•Y)']'
```

Now, from De Morgan's law of boolean algebra,

```
=(X•Y)'' + (X•Y)''
=(X•Y) + (X•Y)
= X•Y
```

Now, if **X=1** & **Y=0**,

```
 X•Y = 1•0 = 0 (Ans.)
```

From the definition of a **NAND** logic gate, *if all the signals passing through a NAND gate are low, i.e., 0, the output is 1. If any signal is high, i.e., 1, the output is 0*. From this,

```
 (1 NAND 0) NAND (1 NAND 0)
=0 NAND 0
=1 (Ans.)
```

From the two methods, we get two different results. Please tell me which one is accepted and also if there is any flaw in either.

Comment: Your first reasoning is correct. The result is "X and Y". The flaw in the second reasoning is that "1 NAND 0" is 1 rather than 0.

Comment: @AxelKemper well, the definition itself says that if all signals are **0** then the output is **1**. If any signal is **1** then the output is **0**. So, how can **1 NAND 0** be **1** and not be **0**? Can you please clear this doubt? Thanks.

Comment: "Nand(x, y)" is "not And(x, y)". Both inputs have to be 1 to yield a 0 output.

Comment: That means the book that says, "**If any signal is 1, the output is 0**" is wrong. That's where I had a problem I guess. I didn't try to verify the definition before. But when I do, `(1•0)' = 1` and `(1•1)' = 0`. Thanks for helping me figure it out @AxelKemper :)

Comment: "If any signal is 1, the output is 0" defines a NOR.

Comment: As per the definition of **NOR** gate in that book, **if all signals are 1, the output is 0. If any signal. If any signal is 0, the output is 1**. Do you think I've been acquainted to these logic gates with the opposite definitions?

Comment: NAND is the inverse (negation) of AND. NOR is the inverse of OR. An AND is true, if all inputs are true. An OR is true, if any input is true. You may want to read the definitions again, perhaps in another book or web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong boolean arthamatics

from you question

> the definition of a NAND logic gate, if all the signals passing through a NAND gate are low, i.e., 0, the output is 1.

is a wrong statment.

Why you are confused in NAND Logic

you mantion above in quistion

> (X NAND Y) = (X•Y)'

then why you shoud use wrong defination(or another deffination).

therefore

> (1 NAND 0) NAND (1 NAND 0) 
>   = 1 NAND 1 = 0 (Ans.) // but you written 0 NAND 0 = 1

[Learn more about NAND Logic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic)

Comment: Thqnyou Prashant for the answer. I'm convinved that book I learned these from definitely had the definitions wrong. This caused all the confusion. Thanks again :)

Comment: Np,,, ask more ,friend.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a **NAND** gate that says, "*If all the input signals are 0, the output is 1. If any signal is 1, the output is 0*" is wrong. The correct explanation of a **NAND** logic gate comes from the algebraic form which is:

```
   X NAND Y
= (X • Y)'
=  X' + Y' ----> (From De'Morgan's law)
```

Thanks to @AxelKemper for helping me reach this conclusion.